# A page that has two buttons but one doesn't work

Tags: android, button

I have a menu page and all the buttons work on it. However, this page is a login page that has 2 buttons: register and login. I wanted to know how I can get my register button to display the register page. Here is my code:

```
public class Login extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.login);


    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
     loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }

    });


     Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
     registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent();
             startActivity(myIntent);
         }
     });

}}
```

Comment: have you defined the register or login page anywhere?

Comment: @MocialovBoris yes I actually had a menu page with a login and register button seperate but now I am combining the two buttons under the login page and need help

Comment: Do you have in mind menu page as something like this: http://developer.android.com/images/options_menu.png  or is it an activity with two button as you have shown in your question?

Comment: As you have said to @MisterSquonk , you have a login page with register button, which means (as i know it) you have an activity with two buttons, one is login and another is register, and they both refer to some other activities, like for example Register.java and Login.java . Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MocialovBoris youre second post is correct

Comment: I made a post, so look at it and say if it suits your solution

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Replace 'RegisterActivity' with the actual name of your register activity but give it the `.class` suffix. This basically is an 'explicit' use of an `Intent` to start a known (named) `Activity`.

Comment: nope doesnt work maybe it will help if I told you I have a menu page and one of the buttons is login and this code is for the login page which contains a login and register button and I need the register button to display the register page

Comment: It would also help if you define 'page' - it doesn't mean anything in Android terminology. In other words, what sort of class/object is the register 'page'?